# Scrolling won't work on mobile (iPhone)

Tags: css, iphone, mobile

Specifically on this page on an iPhone you can't scroll while on top of the picture. I have been trying to figure it out for hours and I'm praying someone here may have some experience.
http://epiqvapor.com/product/cosmic-fog-milk-honey/

Comment: Is there any overflow set on the product image?

Comment: You need to show the code here too

Comment: yes there is overflow

Answer (score 0):

Hi there instead of using an img tag. Use a div and add a background image to it rather.

Instead of

```
<img width="100" height="100" src="example.jpg"/>
```

use

```
<div style="background-image: url('example.jp'); width:100px; height:100px;"></div>
```

This should solve your problem for mobile :)

Comment: Thanks I wish I could, I am limited on what is outputted because it is built with woocommerce in wordpress and there is thumbnail plugin installed as well, I think that is causing some issue also

Comment: So it is the thumbnail that is causing the scrolling issue? do you have access to ftp details? I can maybe guide you on how to put the thumbnail as a background image